# Easy way to generate a contents list and/or site map for a SharePoint Online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My colleague and I inherited an unwieldy SharePoint (SharePoint Online) site and I've been tasked with implementing better organization.

The first step is to figure out what all is in the site - ideally I'd like to create a site map, but even a document list would help. I'm here asking if anyone has a shortcut and/or some code that they've used for this purpose in the past.

We've tried the file report tool that SharePoint has, but it was a bust. We also tried the script I found here [How to list all documents in a SharePoint site with PowerShell](https://collab365.com/list-all-documents/), but it also failed to give a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PnP PowerShell way to get all files from all document libraries of a given site collection to a CSV file.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.SharePoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\DocumentInventory.csv"
$global:DocumentInventory = @()
$Pagesize = 2000
 
#Function to scan and collect Document Inventory
Function Get-DocumentInventory
{
     [cmdletbinding()]
    param([parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] $Web)
   
    Write-host "Getting Documents Inventory from Site '$($Web.URL)'" -f Yellow
    #Calculate the URL of the tenant
    If($Web.ServerRelativeUrl -eq "/")
    {
        $TenantURL = $Web.Url
    }
    Else
    {
        $TenantURL = $Web.Url.Replace($Web.ServerRelativeUrl,'')
    }
 
    #Exclude certain libraries
    $ExcludedLists = @("Form Templates", "Preservation Hold Library","Site Assets", "Pages", "Site Pages", "Images",
                            "Site Collection Documents", "Site Collection Images","Style Library")
                               
    #Get All Document Libraries from the Web
    Get-PnPList -Web $Web -PipelineVariable List | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.Title -notin $ExcludedLists -and $_.ItemCount -gt 0} | ForEach-Object {
        #Get Items from List  
        $global:counter = 0;
        $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $_ -Web $web -PageSize $Pagesize -Fields Author, Created, File_x0020_Type -ScriptBlock `
                 { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($_.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Documents from '$($_.Title)'" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($_.ItemCount)";} | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
        Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Documents from Library $($List.Title)" -Completed
     
            #Get Root folder of the List
            $Folder = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_ -Property RootFolder
 
            #Iterate through each document and collect data          
            ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
            { 
                #Collect document data
                $global:DocumentInventory += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
                    SiteName  = $Web.Title
                    SiteURL  = $Web.URL
                    LibraryName = $List.Title
                    ParentFolder = $Folder.ServerRelativeURL
                    FileName = $ListItem.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
                    FileType = $ListItem.FieldValues.File_x0020_Type
                    AbsoluteURL = "$TenantURL$($ListItem.FieldValues.FileRef)"
                    CreatedBy = $ListItem.FieldValues.Author.Email
                    CreatedAt = $ListItem.FieldValues.Created
                    ModifiedBy = $ListItem.FieldValues.Editor.Email
                    ModifiedAt = $ListItem.FieldValues.Modified
                })
            }
        }
}
  
#Connect to Site collection
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
    
#Call the Function for Web & all Subwebs
Get-PnPWeb | Get-DocumentInventory
Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse| ForEach-Object { Get-DocumentInventory $_ }
Disconnect-PnPOnline
   
#Export Documents Inventory to CSV
$Global:DocumentInventory | Export-Csv $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
Write-host "Documents Inventory Report has been Exported to '$CSVPath'"  -f Green
```

More information:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-all-documents-using-powershell.html